# TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null (Angular7)

Tags: typescript, angular7

When I am creating the package of my module I am getting below error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isSkipSelf' of null at ProviderElementContext._getDependency(C:\Users\ravinder\MyProjectName\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:19242:22
```

I have tried all the possible solutions given on the internet like missing `@injectable`, check dependency injection, circular dependency etcetera. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. Actually, there were two broken imports which were working fine. One of them had a forward slash "/" at the end of the path but TSC was not fetching any error for that, and other was the path of the folder instead of TS file, and for that too TSC was not giving any error.

Comment: I renamed a file from whatever-service.ts to whatever.service.ts but missed one of the imports. The ts compiler was fine with the old path for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

if everything is alright with your code then it must occur due to node modules issue.
try

```
  npm i
```

And try to build the library mostly issue will be solved.